# print corresponding key of dictionary for each element in a set

Tags: python, dictionary, format, set, key-value

I build a dictionary (d) that looks as such:

```
d = {'compartment 1': ['500002', '500012', '305667'],
     'compartment2': ['500002', '500012', '305667', '500010', '500038', '311984'],
     'complex': ['310698', '500072', '308090']}
```

I also build a set of unique elements that correspond to keys of the dict (e.g.'500002') and I know for sure that each element of the set matches a value in dictionary at least once, but possible it has two, three, ... corresponding keys.

What I now want is to print out for each unique element in the set all it's corresponding values on one line.

this is what I came up with:

```
for u in uniqueset:
    for x, y in d.iteritems():
        for number in y:
            if y == u:
                print u, x
```

The result is that it prints every unique item multiple times on different lines. I want it to print it just once on one line, followed by all the keys that correspond. I thought I could do it with a nested for loop, but maybe that's not the way to go about it.

How could I do this?  -- Hope I'm clear.. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension like so

```
>>> [key for key in d if '500002' in d[key]]
['compartment 1', 'compartment2']
```

If you have a set, and you want to find each key that has each item (if I understood your question), you could do this

```
s = set(['308090', '500012', '500072', '305667', '311984', '500010', '500002', '500038', '310698'])

for item in s:
    print item, [key for key in d if item in d[key]]
```

Output

```
308090 ['complex']
310698 ['complex']
311984 ['compartment2']
500038 ['compartment2']
500072 ['complex']
305667 ['compartment 1', 'compartment2']
500012 ['compartment 1', 'compartment2']
500010 ['compartment2']
500002 ['compartment 1', 'compartment2']
```

It you're more comfortable using `for` loops, you can do something like this

```
for item in s:
    keyList = []
    for key in d:
        if item in d[key]:
            keyList.append(key)
    print item, keyList
```

Comment: Thanks so much.. That's amazingly elegant.. I'm always trying not to use comprehensions because I just started to learning scripting and I have difficulty constructing the normal loops etc, so comprehensions make it a bit more complicated to me.. My question is: is there always a way to do it without a comprehension, or would you suggest I just start using the comprehensions?

Comment: Sure thing, you can do anything explicitly in a `for` loop that you can do in a list comprehension. List comprehensions are just more "dense" in that they do the same work in a smaller amount of code, which makes them more tricky to get the hang of.

Comment: If I understand the `if item in d[key]` statement tells to look if item is present in the values of the dictionaries.. 
Is it by default that the values get looked into? 
Not sure if it makes sense, but let's say I want to check if the item is present as key in the dictionary, how would you do that?

Comment: d[key] looks up the list stored under that key, then uses in to see if it has that item. To see if it was a key you could say: item in d.keys()